# What kind of syntax is this in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

```
(postUrl, config, isLoggedIn) = getSpringSecurityLoginConfig()
```

I couldn't find in the official documentation what kind of syntax is this?

Answer (score 5):

That's multiple assignment.

There's a [blog post here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/groovy-goodness-multiple-assignments.html), and [documentation here](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_multiple_assignment):

> Groovy supports multiple assignment, i.e. where multiple variables can be assigned at once, e.g.:
>
> ```
> def (a, b, c) = [10, 20, 'foo']
> assert a == 10 && b == 20 && c == 'foo'
> ```
>
> You can provide types as part of the declaration if you wish:
>
> ```
> def (int i, String j) = [10, 'foo']
> assert i == 10 && j == 'foo'
> ```
>
> As well as used when declaring variables it also applies to existing variables:
>
> ```
> def nums = [1, 3, 5]
> def a, b, c
> (a, b, c) = nums
> assert a == 1 && b == 3 && c == 5
> ```
>
> The syntax works for arrays as well as lists, as well as methods that return either of these:
>
> ```
> def (_, month, year) = "18th June 2009".split()
> assert "In $month of $year" == 'In June of 2009'
> ```

Comment: But the assignment is done to a function of spring security plugin of grails. How would you explain that behavior?

Comment: Actually the assignment is done *from* the right-hand side of the assignment: "a function of spring security plugin of grails". This function apparently returns a list of size 3, and the items of that list are thus each assigned in order *to* the variables listed on the left-hand side of the assignment.